# prove convergence of $|u_m|^{p-2} u_m \to |u|^{p-2} u$ in $L^{p'}(U)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Assume $u_m\to u$ in $L^p(U)$ such that $p>2$.

Prove that $|u_m|^{p-2}u_m \to |u|^{p-2}u$ in $L^{p'}(U)$ where $1/p + 1/p' = 1$.

I did the following: $\||u_m|^{p-2}u_m -|u|^{p-2}u\|_{p'} \le \||u_m|^{p-2}u_m -|u_m|^{p-2}u\|_{p'} + \||u_m|^{p-2}u -|u|^{p-2}u\|_{p'}$

The first term on the RHS can be proved to converge to zero, since $u_m$ converges in $L^p$ , hence the norm $\|u_m\|_p\le M$ . For the second term we apply Holder. There should be a term like this:

$$\int||u_m|^{p-2} - |u|^{p-2}|^{\frac{p}{p-2}}dx$$

I have no idea on how to prove that the term above also converges to zero.For $p-2<1$ we have

$$\int||u_m|^{p-2} - |u|^{p-2}|^{\frac{p}{p-2}}dx \le C\|u_m- u\|_p^p \to 0$$

What about $p>3$?I think the convergence result may not hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I hope you are having a merry christmas!

First it's useful to observe that $p>2 \implies p>p^{\prime}$ and that $||f||_{p^{\prime}}<||f||_p$. Thus $||u_m-u||_{p^{\prime}}<||u_m-u||_{p}\rightarrow 0$, regarding the second half maybe something like using the inequality $|a^p-b^p|\leq |a-b|^p$ when $a,b>0$ and  $0<p<1$. Now first $p^{\prime}=\frac{p}{p-1}$ so $\int_{U}||u_m|^{p-2}-|u|^{p-2}|^{p^{\prime}}=\int_{U}||u_m|^{p-2}-|u|^{p-2}|^{\frac{p}{p-1}}\leq\int_{U}||u_m|-|u||^{\frac{p(p-2)}{p-1}}\leq\int_{U}||u_m|-|u||^{p^{\prime}}=|||u_m|-|u|||_{p^{\prime}}$
and using the reverse triangel inequality $||a|-|b||\leq |a-b|$ we can get $|||u_m|-|u|||_p^p\leq ||u_m-u||_p^p\rightarrow 0$

I think this argument Is valid.

Comment: thanks , Merry Christmas to you too. the inequality $\int_{U}||u_m|^{p-2}-|u|^{p-2}|^{\frac{p}{p-1}}\leq\int_{U}||u_m|-|u||^{\frac{p(p-2)}{p-1}}$ needs $0<p-2<1$ correct?